# R ggvis Combining multiple sliders in one calculated curve layer

Tags: r, dplyr, ggvis

Based on this question of mine: [R ggvis interactive slider for calculating y values (e.g. for background correction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317930), I would like to use several `ggvis` sliders to modify one background correction.

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggvis")
library("lubridate")
data <- data.frame(timestamp = Sys.time() - hours(10:1),
                   signal = rnorm(10),
                   temperature = rnorm(10),
                   secondParameter = rnorm(10))

# mySliderA works fine
mySliderA <- input_slider(0, 2, value = 0, step = 0.1, label = "T-correction", 
                         map = function(x)  data$signal - x * data$temperature)
# mySliderB wants to add a second parameter to the calculation based on mySliderA, this fails.
mySliderB <- input_slider(0, 2, value = 0, step = 0.1, label = "P2-correction", 
                          map = function(x2)  mySliderA - x2 * data$secondParameter )

data %>% 
  ggvis() %>%
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = ~signal,      stroke := "darkgreen") %>%
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = ~temperature, stroke := "red") %>%
  # layer_paths(... y = mySliderA, ...) # would work, but:
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = mySliderB,    stroke := "darkblue")
  # does not.
```

How can I get the second slider to work? Probably, I have to link the `mySliderA`-calculated values differently, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getValue` function from the `observable` attribute of the other slider. To get both sliders, you still need to plot the line with `mySliderA`, but it can of course be transparent.

```
# mySliderA 
mySliderA <- input_slider(0, 2, value = 0, step = 0.1, label = "T-correction", 
                          map = function(x)  data$signal - x * data$temperature)

# mySliderB using `attr(mySliderA, "observable")$getValue()`
mySliderB <- input_slider(0, 2, value = 0, step = 0.1, label = "P2-correction", 
                          map = function(x2)  attr(mySliderA, "observable")$getValue() -
                            x2 * data$secondParameter)
# plotting
data %>% 
  ggvis() %>%
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = ~signal,      stroke := "darkgreen") %>%
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = ~temperature, stroke := "red") %>%
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = mySliderA, stroke := "transparent")  %>% 
  layer_paths(x = ~timestamp, y = mySliderB, stroke := "darkblue")
```

Comment: Ah, great! It pretty much is similar to bits of javascript, then, right? Interesting... Thanks again, @shadow.